# Multiple UserDetailsManager in VaadinWebSecurity

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, vaadin

I am looking for an example how I can use multiple UserDetailsManager or UserDetailsService together with VaadinWebSecurity. Background, I am creating an app with Vaadin Flow and Spring Boot + Security which will have a Frontend for Registered Customers and a Backend for the App Administration. Unfortunately the Data Sources for the users Frontend and Backend will not be the same.

I tried to instantiate two instances of VaadinWebSecurity but it seems not to work, because looking at the source code of Vaadin it is based on named Beans. Only one seems to be supported.

Any suggestions?  I am using Vaadin WebFlow 24, Spring Boot 3 and Spring Security 6.

```
@EnableWebSecurity

@Configuration
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@Slf4j
public class SecurityFrontendConfig extends VaadinWebSecurity {
        @Override
         protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception { ... }
}

@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
@Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)
@Slf4j
public class SecurityBackendConfig extends VaadinWebSecurity {
        @Override
         protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception { ... }
}
```